# How can I send slots to a component in render function in VueJs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, render, vuejs3, vuejs-slots

I have a component like this

```
<template>
  <div class="my-hello">
    Hello {{ man }}
    <slot name="test"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    man: String
  }
})
</script>
```

I want to render this component with render function. My attempt is this, but it is not working.

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({
  render () {
    return h(component, { man: 'David' }, { test: () => h('p', {}, 'SLOT DATA') })
  }
})
app.mount(element)
```

In here `component` is my imported single file vue component (HelloWorld). `element` is some element on the main html.

What's wrong here?

Comment: any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: It works fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sun-s9m8b?file=/src/main.js)

Comment: Interesting. When I send `component` variable through a function (rambda map) it doesn't work. But in its simplest form it works. I think this is not related with vuejs. Something happening to my variable on his journey. :D. And there is no error in console. It simply doesn't render the slot.